# Date object in Firefox always returns milliseconds rounded to hundreds

Tags: javascript, datetime, firefox, rounding

I found this behavior by accident when I recently used `console.time`. In Firefox it always returns either 0ms or 100ms. This happens because the date is always rounded to hundreds of milliseconds. For example `+new Date()` will return `1552469978800` instead of `1552469978877`. Do you know since when is this a thing or how can I possibly get exact time? Also affects `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a final answer to this problem. The whole problem is `privacy.resistFingerprinting` setting enabled by default in recent versions of Firefox.

Fingerprinting protection probably makes more problems than good in this case. You are now completely unable to properly set timezone in Javascript so some web app, for example Slack will always show GMT+0 time instead of your actual time.

Also another annoying thing is that JavaScript animations (especially affecting jQuery plugins) which use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` functions are now running at 10 frames per second.

When you disable fingerprinting protection, everything works fine after you restart the browser.

Answer (score 1):

> This happens because the date is always rounded to hundreds of milliseconds.

I don't see that behavior in Firefox v65 on *nix, nor v48, v56, v57, or v65 on Windows.

But if it's happening in some versions or on some platforms, it may have been a response to [Spectre](https://spectreattack.com/). For the same reason, the alternative I would have pointed out to ([`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)) is less useful than it would otherwise be, because:

> The timestamp is not actually high-resolution. To mitigate security threats such as Spectre, browsers currently round the results to varying degrees. (Firefox started rounding to 1 millisecond in Firefox 60.) Some browsers may also slightly randomize the timestamp. The precision may improve again in future releases; browser developers are still investigating these timing attacks and how best to mitigate them.

Comment: I am using Firefox v65 on Linux and also tested on Firefox v64, results fron both are rounded. Probably some platforms really aren't affected by this. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @lamka02sk - I'm also using Linux, so that's...odd.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```js
function convert( ms ) {
    var seconds = ms / 1000;
    var hours = parseInt( seconds / 3600 );
    seconds = seconds % 3600;
    var minutes = parseInt( seconds / 60 );
    seconds = seconds % 60;
    var pad = function(x) { return (x < 10) ? "0"+x : x; }
    return pad(hours)+":"+
    pad(minutes)+":"+
    pad(seconds);
}
var time = 100000000;
console.log(convert(time));
```

That would convert milliseconds to hours : minutes : seconds format.